# Module parameters still stored in new instances in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

If I load a module that accepts an input object parameter when a new instance is created, the previous values from other instances will be stored in a the new instance if the input object is defined at the parent level of the declared instance. If the input object is defined at the same level as the instance the problem goes away.

I was under the impression that the 'new' operator made the instance completely independent from all others. Why is this happening?

The following example will recreate the behaviour and is made up of two files: test.js and run.js. Please read the comments in run.js to view the issue when running.

test.js:

```
function Test(ob) {
    this.ob = (typeof ob === "undefined") ? {} : ob;
}

Test.prototype.run = function(cb) {
    
    const self = this;

    if (!self.ob.foo) {
        console.log('setting ob.foo');
        self.ob.foo = 'bar';
    } else {
        console.log('ob.foo already set');
    }

    return cb('complete');
}

exports.Test = Test;
```

run.js:

```
const Test = require(__dirname+'/test.js');

// problem exists if parameters set here. :(
const _params = {};

const run = (n) => {
    
    console.log('\ninitializing run '+n);
    
    // no problem if parameter set here. :)
    //const _params = {};
    const test = new Test.Test(_params);
    
    // no problem if not passed in at all. :|
    //var test = new Test.Test();
    
    test.run(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log('');
    });
    
    if (n < 2) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            run(++n);
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        console.log('all runs initialized');
        console.log('--------------------');
    }
    
}

run(1);
```